# htaccess Rewrite for two similar domains, Images not working

Tags: image, .htaccess, url-rewriting, subdomain, root

I have two domains, maindomain.com, and a parked domain, parkeddomain.com. The two have overlaying pages, so I would like to have both hosted from the same host and directory.

For example:

```
www.maindomain.com/index.php?variable=this&page=that
```

is the same info (but with a different layout) as

```
www.parkeddomain.com/DIFFERENTPAGE.php?variable=this&page=that
```

First, I have to say I know little to nothing about htaccess, but I'm pretty sure that's where I should be working. Based off of a few pages I read, I came up with the following code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?parkeddomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/DIFFERENTPAGE.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.parkeddomain.com/DIFFERENTPAGE.php [R=301,L]
```

That was able to load the different pages on my site, but when it came to loading images, it didn't know what to do. The images are all relative to the index.php file. When loaded under the other domain, navigating to www.parkeddomain.com/images/image.png would change the url back to www.parkeddomain.com/DIFFERENTPAGE.php.

If you can help me with this in any way, I would be greatly appreciative!!

Comment: After hours (about 6.5 to be exact), I figured out the solution myself.

I changed line 2 and inserted another line directly beneath it.

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !DIFFERENTPAGE.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

Those changes fixed my issue. I hope this helps others!